# Number Theory books for AMC 12-AIME level

Tags: elementary-number-theory, book-recommendation

I have been prepping a bit for the AMC 12. I've reading the AOPS Counting and Probability Intro, and the start of intermediate, halfway through Intermediate Algebra, and halfway through Number Theory (sometimes I like to switch up what I'm reading). By far the topic in competition math I am worst at is Number Theory. Is there a good book that teaches AMC 12 - AIME level number theory? I have read through quite a bit of AOPS intro to NT, but don't see topics like Euler's phi function, theorem, Fermat's little theorem, etc. covered.

I would also like to know how much number theory is actually covered on the AMC 12, and how much I need to know. I will eventually read more in depth regardless, but in these months leading up to the test I want to try to get the highest score I can.

I tried posting this on AOPS forums but got no reply. I also looked at some other book recommendations, but they seemed more focused towards IMO/USAMO.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you for having the patience to read through this post

Answer (score 0):

Andrews, G. Number Theory. Ed Dover. It is very basic but very didactic, I really liked it. However, if your interest were (for example) to understand the proof of the Fermat-Wiles-Thompson theorem then it falls very very short and you should look for one with the title Analytic Number Theory